# Why does "aws ec2 describe-spot-price-history" include records outside the time range I specified?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Have a look at the image as it's supposed to be worth one thousand words. Has anyone encountered this? Am I missing something or is it just a glitch?

[image: screenshot of output from aws ec2 describe-spot-price-history with red arrows pointing to records with timestamps prior to the --start-time specified]

Answer (score 1):

This output is correct.

The records you have marked as unexpected are the price transitions that established the prices that were actually in effect at the `--start-time` you specified.  If these were not provided in the response, you wouldn't be able to determine the spot price history for the entire time window you requested.